# Need some modification in my code

Tags: java, sql, database, primary-key, sequence

This is a small part of the application where user can register any number of employees and employee id is generated by using a while loop....As i close the application & start filling the data again in second round...the value of employee id **empid** resets to zero. Well, as long as the application is running, i get the desired o/p i.e. a unique id is allotted to every employee. I dont want **empid**'s value to start from 0 whenever i start the application. Need alternatives and/or any modification. Code is provided here

```
int empcount=0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //---------------------If user wants to add data
            if(ae.getActionCommand()=="ADD EMPLOYEE") {
                System.out.println("ADDING");
        try{
            empcount=empcount+1;//----------------will assign employees with unique emp id
            //--------------------returns the text in name field to variables 
            String s_name=name.getText();
            int s_code=empcount;
            String s_dept=dept.getText();
            String s_ph=ph.getText();
            String s_bg=bg.getText();
            String s_add=add.getText();
            String s_date=date.getText();
            PreparedStatement st=null;
            Connection con = null;
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/", "SA", "");
            st=con.prepareStatement("Insert into EmpReg (emp_name,emp_code,emp_ph,emp_bg,emp_add,emp_date,b_id) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            //---------------------parameters and respective values, passed to the SQL statement
            st.setString(1,s_name);
            st.setInt(2,s_code);
            st.setString(3,s_ph);
            st.setString(4,s_bg);
            st.setString(5,s_add);
            st.setString(6,s_date);
            st.setString(7,s_dept);
            st.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is inserted into the database");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(code, "employee code"+ empcount+"");
            con.close();
        }
            catch(Exception Ee){
            System.out.println(Ee);
            }
                }       
            }
        });
```

Comment: text field of empid is non-editable

Comment: If you have a database, either you let the DB generate the ID for you or you use yourself directly a sequence to retrieve a new value everytime. As a last resort, upon startup you can easily invoke `SELECT MAX(empid) from TABLE EMPLOYEE` and increment the value accordingly but beware of multi-threading where you need to synchronize access to the value

Comment: You should remove the database connection code to a background thread instead of querying the DB on the Event Dispatch Thread

Comment: @DavidKroukamp didnt thought that way, just a beginner :p...anyway sounds good...

Comment: @Robin yup u told that few hrs ago...i will do that, the main concern was value of empid

Comment: @GuillaumePolet yup still need any alternative for this...i can make it AUTO_INCREMENT that will do it for me...anyway thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard SQL way of doing this, is having an "autoincrement" primary key (emp_code), for [hsqldb](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch02.html) see IDENTITY.
In the SQL INSERT statement leave out the primary key. Now the database generates a unique new key.
After the execution, you can retrieve the generated primary key from the statement with [getGeneratedKeys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29).

This ensures that two parallel processes will not mess up the primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a field in your DB, that is set to autoIncrementTrue and maybe use it as ID as well. You can also use this field as Employee-Number.

You can check this Link for more Information: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

The generated number will increment every time you insert a new Employee.

Comment: yup thats the way it must be done, however im still looking for an alternative approach, other thn the database one

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DB like Oracle, MySQL, PostGre and use a Sequence or auto generated ID Column to do that for you

Comment: HSQLDB supports sequence as well

Comment: yup it must be done that way, have to AUTO_INCREMENT... still any alternative approach ? thanks anyway :)